# I can't cut of image using "crop" of "pillow"

Tags: python, django, upload, vps

#### Question about django.

Posted image from form was saved and cut it using "crop" of "pillow" then resize and save.

the program was no problem in local, but it was not cuted as specified after deployed on vps (When I upload 5 images, the one or two images was not cuted as specified) .

I just only deployed data of git.

I don't understand the cause.

Could you tell me, if you know the cause.

#### Code

```py
print(int(x))
print(int(y))
print(int(w))
print(int(h))

pp = ImageTable.objects.filter(sort_id = st.sort_id)
print(pp[count-1].image)
im = Image.open('media/' + str(pp[count-1].image)) #'str(pp[count-1].image)' is for example like 'images/test.png' images path

xx = int(x) + int(w)
yy = int(y) + int(h)

im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(xx), int(yy)))
im.resize(size=(200, 200), resample=Image.BOX).save('media/' + str(pp[count-1].image))
```

#### I Tried

About the code above.

the code is looped by for function and upload five images.

it upload different images for each loop because of count is plus 1 every loop.

I confirmed x,y,w,h was as specified value by using print debug.

#### Supplementary information

I hardly changed, but I changed database to postgresql from db.sqlite3.

Is this relevant.

Answer (score 0):

this cause was probably db.
upload was success, but call of image was not success.
when I use ".filter()", image was called descending order at db.sqlite3, but image was not called descending order at postgresql.
I need to use ".filter().order('id')".